# Is there an update/change flag in the current version (v4) of gspread?

Tags: python-2.7, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, flags, gspread

Is there an indicator or flag in *gspread* that indicates whether or not a change has been made to a sheet or worksheet?  This appears to have been present as an attribute called `updated` before version 2.0, or maybe that served a different purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Detect Changes guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-changes) in Drive API.

> For Google Drive apps that need to keep track of changes to files, the
>   Changes collection provides an efficient way to detect changes to all
>   files, including those that have been shared with a user. The
>   collection works by providing the current state of each file, if and
>   only if the file has changed since a given point in time.

There's a [github code demo](https://github.com/googlearchive/drive-pushnotifications-playground) for testing purposes.

Comment: After reading the documentation and the code demo, I am unsure of how I would specify a particular Google Sheets worksheet (tab) that I would like to check for changes...